# How to refer one avro schema inside another one

Tags: avro, avsc

I need to refer to this **Student** schema from inside another schema:

```json
{
  "type": "record",
  "namespace": "data.add",
  "name": "Student",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "Name",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "Age",
      "type": "int"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the parent **Address** schema which needs to refer to **Student**:

```json
{
  "type": "record",
  "namespace": "data.add",
  "name": "Address",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "student",
      "type": "Student"
    }
  ]
}
```

The above throws an error when I build using Gradle with the Avro plugin. Both schemas are located in the same folder.

Answer (score 2):

This was successful:

```json
{
  "type" : "record",
  "namespace" : "data.add",
  "name" : "Address",
  "fields" : [
    {
      "name": "student",
      "type": "data.add.Student"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Note that Avro plus Gradle build is biased in favor of namespaces that match your Java codebase. The majority use case results in `namespace` values like `com.ourcompany.ourservice`

Comment: In the case of two schemas in the same Java namespace, one can simply reference the other like `"type": "Student"`

Comment: I'm still getting error even referencing with namespace as you did. I'm wondering if there any question with my file names ending with 'avsc' extension or with the avro maven plugin.... There is any documentation about this config stuff?

Comment: Doesn't work. What's the plugin version you used?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry if I'm too late to the party, but it looks to me like both the maven avro plugin and the avro-tools compiler do not determine dependency order when loading, but will succeed if you order them yourself on the commandline. I have an example demonstrating this from your sample files in a standard maven directory structure.

When I put the schema with no dependencies first in the commandline, it succeeds:

```sh
java -jar /path/to/avro-tools-1.11.0.jar \
    compile schema  \
    src/main/avro/student.avsc \
    src/main/avro/address.avsc \
    target/generated-sources/avro

ls target/generated-sources/avro/data/add/*
target/generated-sources/avro/data/add/Address.java target/generated-sources/avro/data/add/Student.java
```

When I put the schema with dependencies first in the commandline, it fails:

```sh
java -jar /path/to/avro-tools-1.11.0.jar \
    compile schema  \
    src/main/avro/address.avsc \
    src/main/avro/student.avsc \
    target/generated-sources/avro
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException: "data.add.Student" is not a defined name. The type of the "student" field must be a defined name or a {"type": ...} expression.
    at org.apache.avro.Schema.parse(Schema.java:1676)
    at org.apache.avro.Schema$Parser.parse(Schema.java:1433)
    at org.apache.avro.Schema$Parser.parse(Schema.java:1396)
    at org.apache.avro.tool.SpecificCompilerTool.run(SpecificCompilerTool.java:154)
    at org.apache.avro.tool.Main.run(Main.java:67)
    at org.apache.avro.tool.Main.main(Main.java:56)
```

Answer (score 0):

For Maven one can use the imports configuration.

In this example include the following in your pom.xml under `project/build/plugins`

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
    <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${avro.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>schema</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <imports>
                    <import>${project.basedir}/path/to/student.avsc</import>
                </imports>
                <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/path/to/schema/files</sourceDirectory>
                <includes>
                    <include>*.avsc</include>
                </includes>
                <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/path/to/target/</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

then you should be able to do a maven build...

checkout this link for more details

https://feitam.es/use-of-avro-maven-plugin-with-complex-schemas-defined-in-several-files-to-be-reused-in-different-typed-messages/

Answer (score 0):

We had a scenario where we need to use array of BasketItem in Basket

So we defined schema of BasketItem as below

```
    {
    "type": "record",
    "name": "BasketItem",
    "namespace": "com.demo",
    "fields": [{
            "name": "id",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "name": "shortDesc",
            "type": [
                "null",
                "string"
            ],
            "default": null
        },
        {
            "name": "longDesc",
            "type": [
                "null",
                "string"
            ],
            "default": null
        },
        {
            "name": "requestedQuantity",
            "type": [
                "null",
                "string"
            ],
            "default": null
        }
    ]
  }
```

And then this type BasketItem is used in the Basket schema with reference to namespace.

```
{
    "name": "Basket",
    "type": "record",
    "namespace": "com.demo",
    "fields": [{
            "name": "id",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "name": "creationTimeStamp",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "name": "basketItems",
            "type": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                    "type": "com.demo.BasketItems",
                    "name": "basketItem"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This is simple solution to define reusable Avro schema and refer them as per need, to avoid conflicts in model generation.